# express get routes : how to achieve DRY

Tags: node.js, express

I have code like below to get process paths

```
router.get( "/todoHome", ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "todoHome",
        { title: 'My Todo List!!' } );
} );

router.get( "/articles", ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "articles",
        { title: 'Articles To Read' } );
} );

router.get( ["/", "/index"] ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "index",
        { title: 'Homepage' } );
} );

router.get( "/primary" ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "primaryurls",
        { title: 'Primary DC URLs' } );
} );

router.get( "/standby" ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "standbyurls",
        { title: 'Standby DC URLs' } );
} );
```

I feel like I may add few more similar entries
Is there any way I can implement DRY here ?

Thank you.

Comment: @ggorlen, Added some of the existing entries in my code ( actually I have excluded them to keep my question simple)

Comment: Thanks, this looks more obviously WET to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At best, you can chain those get calls.

```js
router.get( "/todoHome", ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "todoHome",
        { title: 'My Todo List!!' } );
})
.get( ["/", "/index"] ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "index",
        { title: 'Homepage' } );
})
.get(
    //......
)
```

or

```js
const titles = {
    'todoHome' : 'My Todo List',
    'index': 'Homepage',
    ......
}

router.get("*", ( req, res ) => {
    const path = req.path.replace('/', '')
    res.render( path, { title: titles[path] } );
})
```

Also, an advice: Don't try to be a code perfectionist. It will ruin your learning. Welcome to the real world. It's a bit dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the whole thing table-driven which is a goto technique when you have lots of similar looking data being used in repeated functions:

```
const routeData = [
    ['/todoHome', 'todoHome', 'My Todo List!!'],
    ['/articles', 'articles', 'Articles To Read'],
    ['/', 'index', 'Homepage'],
    ['/index', 'index', 'Homepage'],
    ['/primary', 'primaryurls', 'Primary DC URLs'],
    ['/standyby', 'standbyurls', 'Standby DC URLs']
];

// insert routes from the data in the table
for (const [path, name, title] of routeData) {
    app.get(path, (req, res) => {
        res.render(name, {title});
    });
}
```

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ - Did you consider this solution?  This is way, way, way more DRY than the answer you accepted which is what you asked for.  All the accepted answer did was remove a couple references to `router` by chaining the `.get()` calls.  This adds all your routes with four lines of code and a simple table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function, the function will help you render your template.

Something like:

```
function renderPage(resObject, template, title = '', data = {}) {
  resObject.render(template, {
    title,
    ...data,
  });
}
```

then, use the function in the router functions:

```
router.get("/todoHome", (req, res) => {
  return renderPage(res, 'todoHome', 'My Todo List!!')
});
```

Comment: More redonkulous thing than before without any reason. Just additional method to do the same thing with more lines of code. It's like: `function consoleLog(string) {console.log(string)} consoleLog('hi')`. Also, what do you do, when there is something other than title?

Answer (score 0):

I have found another similar solution as below

```
var titleObj = {
    "/kbs": "KB Articles",
    "/articles": "Articles-To-Read"
}

var renderObj = {
    "/kbs": "kbarticles",
    "/articles": "articles",
}

var schemaObj = {
    "/kbs": kbarticlesSchema,
    "/articles": kbarticlesSchema,
}

var routeArray = ["/kbs", "/articles"];

router.get( routeArray, ( req, res ) => {
    console.log( req.path );
    schemaObj[req.path].find()
        .then( ( kbs ) => {
            res.render( renderObj[req.path],
                {
                    title: titleObj[req.path],
                    kbs: kbs
                } );
        } );
} );
```

This way you dont have to touch `router.get` method, and you can keep updating new routes, by updating the respective objects as per your requirement.

Hope it helps.